# Jaws narrator overriding my keyboard navigation functionality

Tags: keyboard-events, jaws-screen-reader, narrator

We are using JAWS narrator software to verify accessibility level AA. We observed on thing related to keyboard navigation. The issue is that we have implemented grid rows navigation using up and down arrow keys.

However when I open Jaws for testing it stops the up/down navigation of Grid rows. In short JAWS functionality of keyboard navigation override my keyboard navigation functionality.

Could you please suggest me any alternative to meet win-win situation?

Answer (score 5):

When using JAWS, in document mode, the arrow keys are used by JAWS to navigate between page elements and tags as in DOM order.

For your case, need to add `role="application"` to the outer html tag, preferably a `div` tag.  This will place JAWS out of document mode and the custom implementation will be working fine.

Here is a slightly modified version SlickGrid with implementation of accessibility to an extent.  This will give a better idea.
http://a11ywidgetsdemo.azurewebsites.net/#/a11ySlickGrid

Tested with JAWS 17.0.1214 and IE11

Comment: You're a life saver, such a simple fix.